# When text copied from MS Word is sent to Java via HTML form, strange characters appear and text length increases

Tags: java, textbox, ms-word

I copied the following text from MS Word and pasted it on the HTML input text field

```
Test…. !! Wow
```

It appeared correctly on the browser and the length was also 13 characters. But when I submit the form, the text received in Java code is

```
Testâ¦. !! Wow
```

with a count of 15. I have a max text field length check in Javascript and in the Java code. Because the text's length increases in Java code, the text might validate in Javascript but fail in Java code. I want the same format in both cases (or at least the same length, so that the validation is consistent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we see here as “â¦” results from the three bytes 0xE2 0x80 0xA6, which constitute the UTF-8 encoded representation of “…” [U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm). The byte 0xE2 is “â” when interpreted as Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252) encoded, and similarly 0xA6 is “¦”. What happens to the 0x80 byte is unclear, but maybe it has been filtered out, because in ISO-8859-1 it is a control character.

Thus, apparently the form data is sent as UTF-8 encoded (this normally depends on the encoding of the page containing the form, though it can also be set with the `accept-charset` attribute in the `<form>` tag). This is all fine, because UTF-8 is the only way to ensure that all characters are *sent* properly.

So the problem is in the receiving side. The Java code appearently reads the data assuming it to be in an 8-bit encoding (one byte = one character), but it isn’t.

(The reason why the text contains U+2026 is probably autocorrection in Word: by default, Word turns, in keyboard input, three consecutive periods “...” to one character, the ellipsis “…”.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently, Java uses the system's default encoding (which is UTF-8 on my Ubuntu) and UTF-16 for text representation. I really can't understand what could be wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an encoding problem. The characters you're pasting will be UTF-8 (or similar), but will be being sent as ANSI characters. You need to set your encoding for the submit.

Comment: Yes.. but I can't figure out how to do it. How do I detect what encoding was used in the text pasted and how to make sure that it is sent in the correct encoding... Anything to be done at the Java side ?